# Angular 2 sub routing not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to implement child router in my application.
what I did is, on click of side menu , I am navigating to the child as

```
this._router.navigate(['/parent/child']);
```

but its not executing the child component, instead parent component is getting executed again.

router in app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
   {path:'parent',
       children:[
           {path: '', component: ParentComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
          ,{path:"child",component:ChildComponent,
             outlet:'content'
           }]
   },
   {path:'**',component:LoginComponent}
 ];
```

ParentComponent

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import {Router} from '@angular/router';
 import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'login',
   templateUrl: 'app/parent.template.html'
 })
 export class ParentComponent  implements OnInit{  
  constructor(private _router: Router){} 
   ngOnInit(){}
   menuClicked(event:any):void{             
        let elements = event.target.parentElement.children;
        for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
            elements[i].classList.remove('active')
        }
        event.target.classList.add('active');
        this._router.navigate(['/parent/child']);
    }
 }
```

ChildCOmponent:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import {Router} from '@angular/router';
 import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/child.template.html',
 })
 export class IncidentComponent  implements OnInit{  
    constructor(private _router: Router){} 
    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

What happened is, it navigated to parent and its working fine. When i click left menu, i can see the url change for a fraction of seconds and then its reloading the parent, removing the child name from the url. How can i fix it? What I missed in the implementation?

Parent Template

```
<div class="home-container row">
   <div class="home-body col-12">
       <div class="home-header row">

       </div>
       <div class="home-contents row">
          <div class="left-menu col-2">
          </div>
       <div class="right-contents col-10">
          <router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just remove `pathMatch: 'full'` and check.

Comment: Same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982077/angular-child-route-not-working-and-redirect-me-to-the-same-page/50982752#50982752 Try that solution

Comment: can you show the parent component html file ?

Comment: parent template added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often caused by where your `<router-outlet>`  is. It is supposed to be the only changing part of your application 
Check where is located if it is not located in the main component

Comment: I edited my response, sorry the router-outlet wasn't rendered. Can you also share your parent component

Comment: Edited. parent component added now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this._router.navigate(['child'],{relativeTo: this.route});
```

Here this.route is an instance of ActivatedRoute.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
```